How to enable Message Persistence on AmazonMQ to avoid losing messages due to maintenance window?
Our team has single instance AmzonMQ broker with the following configuration:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<broker schedulePeriodForDestinationPurge="10000" xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core">

  <destinationPolicy>
    <policyMap>
      <policyEntries>
        <policyEntry gcInactiveDestinations="false" inactiveTimoutBeforeGC="600000" topic="&gt;">
          <pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
            <constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy limit="1000"/>
          </pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
        </policyEntry>
        <policyEntry gcInactiveDestinations="false" inactiveTimoutBeforeGC="600000" queue="&gt;"/>
      </policyEntries>
    </policyMap>
  </destinationPolicy>
  <plugins/>
</broker>


When there is a maintenance window we lose all messages in the queue's "Number Of Pending Messages" (and all the rest of course but that one is more important).
I want to find out if adding:
  <persistenceAdapter>
    <kahaDB/>
  </persistenceAdapter>

will ensure that those messages are preserved after the maintenance window.
To test what I have done before adding the above persistenceAdapter block

I pushed a message to one of the queues we have - "us-s1-PDF_DATA_EXTRACTION"
I rebooted the broker manually using the AWS Console
Checked the admin ActiveMQ page and the count of the "us-s1-PDF_DATA_EXTRACTION" queue was still set to 1

I am a bit confused, how does that message get preserved without having the persistenceAdapter block in the broker's configuration? Also, does the maintenance window do something extra to that causes the queue's messages to get deleted when message persistence is not enabled (i.e. adding persistenceAdapter block)?


I opened a case with AWS Support and here is what they said:
Message persistence is enabled by default on AmazonMQ ActiveMQ by default but the producer needs to specify whether or not it sends the message with persistence. You have this configured correctly as above.
So as long as the producer makes a message to be persisted (see below from the Java example) it will be persisted on the broker's EFS storage.
setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.PERSISTENT)

